How to tell if a user is part of a secured domain?
Say you are in a company XYZ, domain XYZ.com.
You develop a software that requires a license for your clients to run it. But to make it easier for you and your colleagues to develop and test, you want the licensing check to be bypassed if the user is on the XYZ domain.
Checking what domain a user is part of is easy, if you only care about having the domain name. But if you want to prevent a malicious entity to use your software for free by making a dummy local domain "XYZ.com", you will want something more robust.
I am aware of Windows Security Identifiers (SID) and how on paper you can extract the first part to distinguish your trusted domain from one with the same name. But in practice this will eventually fail as there is no guarantee for a domain to keep the same domain identifier. I can attest that in my case I can see disparities when looking at different users.
Without making a 100% impervious system, is there a way to reliably tell we are part of a specific instance of a domain? Some certificate GUID maybe?

Why don't you create a system to grant a specific license type upon request and add a human element to it?  There is no way you can make a license system to check the name of an Active Directory because a user can make that anything they want.
